# Receive Notification Multiple time Using FCM. How to stop it?

Tags: android, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I am using FCM for push notification. But when I send notification on Firebase console for testing purpose. It receives multiple time. How it is possible.  Please provide me relevant solution.

Comment: Please provide relevant code or some other details. Now it is unclear

Comment: @Kotov  i only add new project and config it with firebase. i just added google.json file and nothing other code write on it. It's also working fine before some days.

Comment: WakefullBroadcast Receiver has been deprecated. That's may be reason to receive notifications multiple time. Use default firebase receiver to handle this situation.

Comment: This worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48785262/receiving-the-fcm-notifications-multiple-times-on-nougat/49177709#49177709